# A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x6172724d in tid 3789 (mqt_js), pid 3388

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, error-handling, fatal-error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CHOwL.jpg)On react native android app, when Gradle is finished and app is installed in android-studio, app getting show first page and closing in one second, in LogCat was shown:
2022-09-08 13:22:05.201 3388-3789/com.megonative A/libc: Fatal [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wqb1h.jpg)signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x6172724d in tid 3789 (mqt_js), pid 3388 (com.megonative)

Have anybody solution for this fatal error?

https://files.fm/u/wrzu8n996
(Link of Screenshot from logcat.)

Comment: Can you please share full log? It is highly likely that the error is below/above this one.

Comment: https://files.fm/u/wrzu8n996
@dev404

Comment: this is link of screenshot from logcat

Comment: Can you please try with by selecting "No filters" from the right side of logcat, and setting the filter types to "Error" rather than "Verbose". And you might want to filter using your app like "megonative" in the search box.

Comment: Oh, btw are you using expo? If yes, then can you please share the expo version as well?

Comment: there was so many errors, it does not matter I will do new react native project -_- Im using CLI

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

When canvas duplicated current bitmap it gives error like this